# Transactional Messaging API - can it be configured NOT to create billable contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, transactional-messaging-api

I know how it works for Triggered Sends -

[Does Triggered Send count against total contacts in Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307704/does-triggered-send-count-against-total-contacts-in-marketing-cloud/307708#307708)

and the notable difference between All Contacts / All Subscribers.

Question:
Can the "new" transactional API used in a way that does not create billable contact records?
Meaning that it could be used using external Ids for recipients (e.g. non-Salesforce Ids) paying only the Super Messages for the sendout, not creating additional billable Contacts that might have to be deleted.
I couldn't find any reference in the documentation on that, and since Contact Count is not easy to determine in real-time, I don't trust my own tests from a while back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer NO,

Every subscriber sent to within SFMC has to be a contact, there is no way to send a message without creating a contact.

As far as counts go the All Contacts screen in contact builder is an accurate representation of contacts (just doesn't dedupe by subkey)

This help article: '[Contact Definition and Count Determination in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5)' is inclusive of what a contact is.

> A contact is also a person to whom you sent a message via any Marketing Cloud channel, including these examples:
>
> Journey Builder
> MobileConnect
> MobilePush
> GroupConnect