# Unable to setup Triggered Send through Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm trying to create the following process:

1. Fill out AMPscript based form which either creates or updates a record on the Custom Object Product Registrations.
2. After creation or update a Triggered Send needs to be send through Marketing Cloud Connect
3. The Object is synced to Marketing Cloud.

Step 1 and 3 are working like they should, however step 2 is not. This is the issue I'm facing:

I'm following the documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_create_a_triggered_send.htm&type=5 and after I've created the Apex script I'm trying to configure the Triggered Send in the Marketing Cloud tab, however I'm unable to select the Recipient Lookup based on the Product Registration Object (ContactID is connected in this Object) and also when I'm trying to create a record manually I'm getting the following error:

*UM_ProductRegistration_Trigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: et4ae5.MCBaseException.InvalidParameterException: Whoops! Marketing Cloud Connect does not have access to the selected object. Contact your administrator to enable objects for Marketing Cloud Connect triggered sends. Class.et4ae5.triggerUtility.validateAndPerformTriggerSend: line 52, column 1 Class.et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate: line 37, column 1 Trigger.UM_ProductRegistration_Trigger: line 1, column 1*

I can confirm that the object is syncing to Marketing Cloud.

Has anyone faced this same issue before or knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I would dare say this is a bit of an "uncommon" way to do things these days, with Journey Builder being what it is today, but there might be valid reasons to go this route. Googling your error message brings up 4 year old stuff exclusively, that's also about the last time I did it this way. Is your user "integrated" in MC Connect?

Comment: @JonasLamberty, yes it is. The main reasons why I'm doing it like this is to prevent having SubscriberKeys in the All Subscribers and Contact ID's in Data Extensions and Journey Builder. There is also the option to trigger the Send by Ampscript on the Cloudpage, however that would create the SubscriberKey. Do you see any other option for this?

Comment: If you do all this because you do not want to pay for the billable Contact, then stop right there. It WILL create one, not writing the record to All Subscribers or into DEs etc. just obscures that and makes the eventual issue of "how did I get to so many contacts" harder to resolve. I am not aware of any method that doesn't create Contacts when sending. My last hope was transactional API, but no luck so far:  - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328050/transactional-messaging-api-can-it-be-configured-not-to-create-billable-contac ;

Comment: more on all subscribers / all contacts here: https://deselect.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud-data-model-part-3-how-to-manage-data-in-contact-builder/

There used to be a thing in the contact report called "triggered send hidden list count". It's since been renamed, but you would expect your triggered sends to create contacts through that even if they are not written to all subscribers.

Comment: I would advise instead to think of a flagging mechanism for the relevant records and a contact deletion process, which you can find a lot about on stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, however the billable Contact is not the reason why we want to go for this option. If we can trigger an email based on a change happening on the custom object we are going to prevent a duplicate in records (one created in All subscribers based on the triggered send and one coming from Sales cloud). So it's simply the process: form submission > create or change record > send triggered email > sync to Marketing Cloud

Comment: Daan, nice to see you here :D I can think of two things. Did you perform step 13 in this checklist? 

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_configure_objects_and_triggers.htm&type=5

If so, make sure the marketing cloud user has access to the object in Sales Cloud. Either by updating the profile or using a permission set. 

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects

Comment: Thanks @RickForce, I did :). I'm now working on an AMPscript solution which solved the initial question.

Comment: @JonasLamberty, thanks for the proposed solutions. I've got it working with AMPscript